# Would Bitcoin-Qt ever use an imported private key's public key as a future change address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, import

Let's say I import a paper wallet's private key into my Bitcoin-Qt client.  I then manually sweep the entire balance from that private key to a different Bitcoin-Qt private key/address with a new transaction.

Will Bitcoin-Qt ever send change from a future transaction to the paper wallet's imported private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only new addresses are used for change.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you manually select the imported key's address as a change address in Coin Control.